# Are these queries valid?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, coffeescript

EDIT: figured out how to query an array.

What about querying for a field in an object with dot notion?

```
attributes:
    colors: 'red'

collection.findOne {attributes.colors:'red'}, (doc) ->
     #returns that doc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote an attribute with a dot in it:

```
collection.findOne 'attributes.colors': 'red', (doc) ->
  # returns that doc
```